# Select data from Multidimensional List

Tags: c#

can somebody help me? How can I get `List<Episode>` from `List<Show>` where `Episodes.Seen == false`?

```
public class Show
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

public class Episode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Seen { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much for tour help.

Comment: Use LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `Linq` statment.

```
var episodes = shows.SelectMany(s=>s.Episodes.Where(e=>e.Seen.HasValue && !e.Seen.Value));
```

Comment: Probably because you used `Select` instead of `SelectMany`

Comment: @QualityCatalyst That is not a valid edit, it could be a decent comment though. However, the questions implies it's a `List<Show>`

Comment: @DavidG it was fast type which caused a typo, noticed only when I see down vote :-)

Comment: [+] for `e.Seen.HasValue` for the `Nullable`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LINQ, like so:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<Episode> unseenEpisodes = (from show in shows
                        from episode in show.Episodes
                        where (episode.Seen.HasValue && episode.Seen.Value == false)
                        select episode);
```